# Role of chemical potential in bosonic gas

Tags: statistical-mechanics

How does the chemical potential allow us to distinguish different quantum gas? In particular, why is it true that [bosonic gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose_gas) always has chemical potential smaller than or equal to $0$?

Comment: The gist is (for a photon gas at least) that photons don't interact with each other thus we generally say they have zero chemical potential. However if a photon gas interacts with Fermions (for example, electrons and holes in a semiconductor) then the chemical potential of the photon gas becomes the same as the chemical potential of the electrons and holes. I'm afraid that I can't state that in more general statistical mechanics terminology and my knowledge is specific to photons. But it's an interesting question, hope you get an answer.

Comment: Its a pretty big answer. Refer to Pathria Chap. 6, Theory of Simple Gases. To answer your question shortly its go to do with the summation of the partition function.